# Limited field type options QGIS 3.4

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes

I'd like to add a 'Decimal Number (double)' field to an attribute table, however, this option seems to be missing when I go to add a field. I have looked at some videos for adding fields in QGIS and noticed that others have many more field type options than I do, including the 'Decimal number (double)'. Below is a list of the field types I can currently choose from:

- Whole number (integer)
- Whole number (integer 64bit)
- Decimal number (real)
- Text (string)
- Date
- Date and time

Why are my options more limited than others and how can I get the options I need? I'm using QGIS v3.4 Madeira.

Comment: The Decimal field type will allow you to set the length and precision... that should be what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The field types are dependent on the layer's backend -- e.g. you'll see a different set of available field types for a PostGIS layer vs a shapefile vs a Geopackage.

Comment: Thank you, this cleared up my confusion. I was working with a file saved to a local folder, but when I added the same file from PostGIS I saw additional field types listed.